# verify void method call

Tags: java, testing, junit, mocking, easymock

I have the following classes:

```
public class A {
    private Field field;
    public A(Field field){
        this.field = field;
    }
    public add(int size){
        field.addBall(new Ball(size));
    }
}

public interface Things {
    List<Ball> ballList = new LinkedList<>();
    public addBall(Ball b){
        ballList.add(b);
    }
}
```

And I want to test add() method of A class. To be more specific I want to test if addBall() method of class Things is called. 
This test fails saying: Expectation failure on verify : Things.addBall(...)  : expected: 1 ,actual: 0;

```
public class TestA {
        private Things thing;
        private A a;
        @Before
        public void setUp() {
            thing = EasyMock.createNiceMock(Things.class);
            a = new A(thing);
        }

        @After
        public void tearDown() {
        }
    @Test
        public void addTest(){
            thing.addBall(new Ball(345));
            EasyMock.expectLastCall();
            EasyMock.replay(cache);
            a.add(345);
        EasyMock.verify(cache);
        }
}
```

What is the right approach? What is wrong whit this test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume the variable called `cache` is in fact `thing`. Then, the other answer is right. The parameters are using the equals matcher by default. And you probably have not defined equals on `Ball`.

I did different implementations to show how you can solve this problem without adding an `equals` method.

Some comments about the code:

- You don't need a nice mock here. A normal mock is in fact safer
- I love static imports for my test code :-)
- `expectLastCall` isn't necessary. It is by default for a void method
- There was a lot of compilation errors that I fixed. Try to give working examples next time

First the fixed code:

```
public class Things {
  List<Ball> ballList = new LinkedList<>();

  public void addBall(Ball b){
    ballList.add(b);
  }
}

public class A {
  private Things field;

  public A(Things field){
    this.field = field;
  }

  public void add(int size){
    field.addBall(new Ball(size));
  }
}
```

I've added a `getSize` to `Ball` to have realistic examples.

```
public class Ball {

  private final int size;

  public Ball(int size) {
    this.size = size;
  }

  public int getSize() {
    return size;
  }
}
```

And finally, `TestA`

```
public class TestA {
  private Things thing;
  private A a;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    thing = createMock(Things.class);
    a = new A(thing);
  }

  @Test
  public void addTest(){
      // You should keep only one of these examples
      // 1. You don't care about checking `345`. You just want to make sure there is a call. `anyObject` is exactly what you need
     thing.addBall(anyObject());
     // 2. You want to expect a `Ball` with `345` 
     thing.addBall(cmp(new Ball(345), Comparator.comparingInt(Ball::getSize), LogicalOperator.EQUAL));
    // 3. You prefer a simpler check possibly on many attributes. Just capture the `Ball` passed in parameter and check after if it contains what you want
    Capture<Ball> capture = Capture.newInstance();
    thing.addBall(capture(capture));
    // Now the original code
    replay(thing);
    a.add(345);
    verify(thing);
    // Assert on the capture is you used solution #3
    assertEquals(345, capture.getValue().getSize());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually go with Mockito, but here is my guess:

When EasyMock compares the result of `new Ball(345)` you passed to recording phase with the result of `new Ball(size)` inside `a.add(345)`, you're looking at two completely different `Ball` objects. They do not compare `equal()`, although the size is the same.

As a general rule, explicit calls to `new` are trouble when you test. One possible solution is to introduce `BallFactory`. Then you can verify that the `factory.createBall(345)` was called, and its result, a mock of a `Ball` is the one passed to `addBall()`

(Here is an excellent article on this topic: http://misko.hevery.com/2008/07/08/how-to-think-about-the-new-operator/ )

If you'd rather relax your test requirements and just check if `addBall()` gets called with any object (I'd advise against that), you can use [anyObject()](http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/EasyMock.html#anyObject-java.lang.Class-) method of EasyMock to match any `Ball`.

Comment: Im not comparing the Balls Im only testing if addBall() gets called at all.

Comment: EasyMock compares the recorded args, not just the fact of call. (see my edit)

Comment: Arkady is correct; your Ball class needs to @Override equals() in order to make that test work as it is written right now.

Comment: Ohhh, I see well thats the worst I could imagine. Didnt want to paste the original code cz its a lot more complex but fine. Is there any way to not compare the argument? Ty the answers gents.

Comment: Please look at the bottom of the answer for a way to match any argument value (that should be same as not checking at all).

Comment: Yeah for the first try It worked on a simple case where the code was as simple as my example code but then I decided to override equals cz overriding equals is always good idea on a properly implemented model representation even if you never use it anywhere else.TY for the answers I never thought that EasyMock checks the parameters at all.